# String.format uses comma instead of point

Tags: android, floating-point, android-edittext

My app is working on many devices without problems so far. But now I got my new Galaxy Tab with Android 3.2 where it crashes all the time. I found out that the problem was a float in an EditText.
I am using `myEditText.setText(String.format("%.1f", fMyFloat));` to put the float in the EditText. But somehow the float on my 3.2 Galaxy Tab is generated with a comma instead of a point. When I read the EditText back the app crashes of course, telling me that this is no valid float because of the comma...

What is going wrong here?

Comment: may be locale issue.change your locale to other from setting of your Galaxy TAB and give a try again...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Convert float to string..

From the documentation of `String.format`:

> **[String.format(String format, Object... args)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)**
>
> Returns a localized formatted string, using the supplied format and arguments, using the user's default locale.

The quoted text above means that the output of `String.format` will match the default locale the user uses.

As an example a comma would be used as the decimal-point-delimiter if it's a user using Swedish locale, but a dot if it's using an American.

If you'd like to force what locale is going to be used, use the overload of `String.format` that accepts three parameters:

- [**String.format (Locale locale, String format, Object... args)**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

---

#### Convert string to float..

Parsing an arbitrary string into a float using the default locale is quite easy, all you need to do is to use [`DecimalFormat.parse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Then use [`.parse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%28) to get a [`Number`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Number.html) and call [`floatValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Number.html#floatValue%28%29) on this returned object.

Answer (score 6):

Your `format` call on your Galaxy Tab uses some default `Locale` which in turn uses `,` for floats. You could use [`String.format(Locale,String,...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) version with specific locale to make things work.

Or you should've used same locale both for parsing and formatting the number. So you should probably go with `NumberFormat` to format and parse your floats.

Comment: That call of `String.format` is also a good candidate. In fact you can use it with the Locale as `null` and forget about the locale if you don't need it ;)

Answer (score 5):

`String.format` uses the locale you are in. You should do something like this if you want a dot:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
myEditText.setText(formatter.format(fMyFloat);
```

Have a look into [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for more formatting options

Answer (score 4):

Use below code it's works for me:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern(pattern);
String output = df.format(value);
System.out.println(pattern + " " + output + " " + loc.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Summing up previous answers, an easy way to have the dot instead of the comma in all country, is this:

```
myEditText.setText(Locale.CANADA, String.format("%.1f", fMyFloat));
```

And you will have your String formatted with the dot