# String format and locale problems - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

When I perform a truncate using:

```
label.setText(String.format("%.2f", 1.2975118));
// 1,30
```

I get comma(,) instead of point(.) and this causes my program crash since I need to perform operation on float numbers.

How I can truncate a float and `.setText` with a point instead of comma?

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601011/string-format-uses-comma-instead-of-point?answertab=votes#tab-top), an equal question.

Comment: May sound stupid but after your format you could try replacing all commas with points. Using the `.replaceAll();`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please be careful as String.format depend on your current Local configuration, you may not get a dot as a separator.

**Prefer using** `String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.2f", floatValue);`

**Locale independent :**

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.2f", floatValue) worked^^ thanks!

Comment: tested DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");, it depends on Locale too

Comment: it worked, but for me I don't need add decimail, so I did like this String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%,d", amount.toInt())